Can't read an object
I've been trying to get the id of $meal for 3 hours without success:
use App\Models\Recipe;
use App\Models\Meal;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
        // Meal data
            // Function to generate combinations of recipes
            function generateCombinations($items, $n, $start = 0, $result = [], &$results = []) {
                if ($n === 0) {
                    $results[] = $result;
                    return;
                }
            
                for ($i = $start; $i < count($items); $i++) {
                    $result[] = $items[$i];
                    generateCombinations($items, $n - 1, $i + 1, $result, $results);
                    array_pop($result);
                }
            }
            // Function to filter combinations by total calories
            function filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCaloriesMin, $dailyCalories) {
                return array_filter($combinations, function($combination) use ($dailyCaloriesMin, $dailyCalories) {
                    $totalCalories = array_sum(array_column($combination, 'calories'));
                    return $totalCalories >= $dailyCaloriesMin && $totalCalories <= $dailyCalories;
                });
            }
            // Function to get daily meal plan
            function getDailyMealPlan($dailyCalories, $dailyCaloriesMin) {
                $mealCategories = ['breakfast', 'lunch-dinner', 'snacks'];
                $mealPlan = [];
            
                foreach ($mealCategories as $category) {
                    $recipes = Recipe::where('meal', $category)->get()->toArray();
            
                    $combinations = [];
                    generateCombinations($recipes, $category === 'snacks' ? 1 : 2, 0, [], $combinations);
            
                    $filteredCombinations = filterCombinationsByCalories($combinations, $dailyCaloriesMin, $dailyCalories);
            
                    if (empty($filteredCombinations)) {
                        $selectedRecipe = Recipe::where('meal', $category)->orderBy('calories', 'desc')->first();
                        $mealPlan[$category] = $selectedRecipe;
                    } else {
                        $selectedCombination = $filteredCombinations[array_rand($filteredCombinations)];
                        $mealPlan[$category] = $selectedCombination;
                    }
                }
            
                return $mealPlan;
            }

        // Usage
        $dailyCalories = $deficit_tdee_calories; // ex: 1500
        $dailyCaloriesMin = 1300; // ex: 1300
        $mealPlan = getDailyMealPlan($dailyCalories, $dailyCaloriesMin);
        foreach ($mealPlan as $meal) {
            Meal::create([
                'meal_id' => $meal['id'],
            ]);
        }
}

I want to get the id inside this object.
with print_r($meal):
App\Models\Recipe Object ( [connection:protected] => mysql [table:protected] => recipes [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [preventsLazyLoading] => [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => [escapeWhenCastingToString:protected] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 29 [recipe] => Creamy Cheese Pancakes [category] => Breakfast Recipes [meal] => breakfast [image] => Creamy_Cheese_Pancakes-Creamy_Cheese_Pancakes.jpg [calories] => 82 [created_at] => [updated_at] => ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 29 [recipe] => Creamy Cheese Pancakes [category] => Breakfast Recipes [meal] => breakfast [image] => Creamy_Cheese_Pancakes-Creamy_Cheese_Pancakes.jpg [calories] => 82 [created_at] => [updated_at] => ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [classCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [attributeCastCache:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [timestamps] => 1 [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [fillable:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) )

with dd($meal):
App\Models\Recipe {#1388 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "recipes"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:8 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

If I do print_r($meal->id) or print_r($meal['id']) or dd($meal->id) I get the id:
29

But if I do $id = $meal['id'], i get this:
Undefined array key "id"

If I do $id = $meal->id:
Attempt to read property "id" on array

I don't understand why.
I tried:
$id = $meal[0]['id'];

Also tried:
$json_decode = json_decode($meal, true);
$id = $json_decode['id'];

What am I doing wrong?

There's no way that $meal['id'] can work in print_r() but not in an assignment. The argument to print_r() is not treated specially.

Are you sure you didn't reassign $meal between the print_r() calls and the assignments? It looks like it changed from an object to an array.

Please post a [mre], including the definition of the Recipe class.

@Barmar when I do print_r($meal['id']) it shows 29. I just tried again.
I didn't reassign $meal

I don't know of any way that using the expression can work differently in print_r() than assignment. There are some functions that suppress warnings from their arguments (e.g. isset() and empty()), but AFAIK print_r() is not one of them.

Notice that id is not actually a property of $meal. It's in the attributes property, and the class uses a magic method to look it up from there. But it should work the same in an assignment.

@Barmar Very strange. I added my full code.

And you're getting an error from 'meal_id' => $meal['id']?

@Barmar yes I got an error from 'meal_id' => $meal['id']. Error is Undefined array key "id"

I don't think anyone can answer this without knowing how the Recipe class works. It looks like you're using an ORM, please add a tag for the ORM you're using so people familiar with it will see the question.

You are mixing results from different execution paths within your app, that is why your results doesn't make sense. Once you get array from Recipe::where('meal', $category)->get()->toArray(); and then object from Recipe::where('meal', $category)->orderBy('calories', 'desc')->first();, you either need to use same data type or distinguish between them as the usage is different, often model objects do not have array adapters just to not misuse them.
Also method generateCombinations is wild, as it produce array with different dimensions ($n = 1 vs $n = 2), duplicate data too (more items in $items will produce more duplicates), which is not taken into account.
